# The derivative of $-|s|^{p-2}s$

Tags: analysis

In many papers, I can see the derivative of $-|s|^{p-2}s$ $(p\ge 2, s\in R)$ is less than a positive constant. I don't know how to derive it? Please give me some help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can clearly assume $p>2$ (for $p=2$ the derivative is constantly $-1$).

For $s\ne0$, the standard formulas work: if $f(s)=-|s|^{p-2}s$, then
$$
f'(s)=-(p-2)|s|^{p-3}\frac{|s|}{s}s-|s|^{p-2}=-(p-1)|s|^{p-2}
$$
It remains to show what happens at $0$:
$$
\lim_{s\to0}\frac{f(s)-f(0)}{s-0}=\lim_{s\to0}-|s|^{p-2}=0
$$
which agrees with the previous function for $s=0$, so we can state that
$$
f'(s)=-(p-1)|s|^{p-2}
$$
for all $s$.

What is the meaning of “the derivative is less than a positive constant” is not at all clear: the derivative is negative except at $0$.

Comment: Thanks, I have got it!  I have made a mistake when I did some calculations. It is less and equals 0, so it is also less than any positive constants.